# Show PDF on a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I found an [example code](https://github.com/iamruinous/Reader/downloads) for showing PDF file on a UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling. It works fine, but problem is it shows **only 2 pages of PDF**. I tried in my best to figure out the issue, but I couldn't figure it. Can you please give me help?

Comment: When you load your PDF via the `PDFContainer` class, does it have the correct number of pages?

Comment: @ Simon Lee yes, it has correct number of pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at that sample project you pointed to in this question and like you, I can see it only displays two pages of whatever PDF file it's given to display.

The problem with the sample code comes in the PDFViewController.m file.  For these lines:

```
PDFScrollView *page = [self dequeueRecycledPage];
if (page == nil) {
    page = [[[PDFScrollView alloc] initWithPage:index + 1 frame:[self frameForPageAtIndex:index]] autorelease];
}
```

I added

```
else {
    [page setPage: index inFrame:[self frameForPageAtIndex: index]];
}
```

And also these new lines into PDFScrollView.h

```
- (void) setPage: (NSInteger) onPage inFrame:(CGRect)frame;
```

And PDFScrollView.m

```
- (void) setPage: (NSInteger) onPage inFrame:(CGRect) frame
{
    if(pdfView)
    {
        [pdfView removeFromSuperview];
        [pdfView release];
    }
    self.frame = frame;
    self.index = onPage;
    pdfView = [[PDFViewTiled alloc] initWithPage:onPage frame:self.frame];
    [self addSubview:pdfView];
}
```

This isn't a perfect fix.  You'll see the drawing isn't proper, especially when backing up pages.  I'll leave that to you as an exercise to take care of, but hopefully this is a nice start.

And I hope it helps you out.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, I found really useful open source example. I'll share it  http://www.vfr.org/